# How do I update my python version in vs code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Ive already downloaded the newest version on the offical python website, I just need it to get to vs code somehow.

I went to the website, downloaded the newest version, and I restarted my computer to hopefully get it to connect to vs code somehow. And obviously, that didnt work. I read countless articals on how to do this another way, and they didnt seem to help.

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for stackoverflow and will probably be locked. Even if this was the right place to ask, then the question would be unanswerable because you didn't provide any specific information about your environment. So, in general, you need to make sure that the new python version is in your system's path. Then, in VS Code, select the interpreter by clicking in extreme the bottom-right corner of the window. Even better would be to use a virtual environment so VS Code always grabs the right interpreter for your project.

Comment: Did you read this? [Working with Python interpreters](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters) [Using Python Environments in Visual Studio Code]

Comment: Did you install it? Please [edit] to clarify. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for tips.

Comment: I would suggest working with pyenv  and pyenv-virtualenv, and create virtualenvs. This way, each project can use a different python version and set of libraries / packages. VSCode does pick up the correct python version automatically.

Comment: @picobit What makes you say this isn't the right place to ask? I agree it's missing info and could be *closed* until clarified, but it is [on-topic](/help/on-topic) since it's about programming tools. And then why are you giving advice after turning OP away? That's sending mixed messages. Instead, if I were you, I'd urge OP to edit the question to clarify the problem, which is exactly what I've done above.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of installing multiple versions of Python in your system, I would suggest you [create a virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/venv.html). This will help avoid conflicts that may arise as a result of having multiple versions of Python installed in your system. The virtual environment is a self-contained directory tree that contains a Python installation for a particular version of Python, plus a number of additional packages.

**Edit** To do this, use:
`python -m venv test-env`
This will create the test-env directory if it doesn’t exist, and will create directories inside that contains the Python interpreter.

Comment: ... not quite accurate. You still need to make sure to create the virtual environment _using the correct version of Python_. If you have, say Python 3.9, 3.10, 3.11 versions all in one machine, then when creating the virtual env, you need to make sure to specify the right Python version. How to do that depends on which virtual env you are using, but for example, `python3.10 -m venv ...`, `pipenv install --python=/path/to/python3.9`, .etc. Otherwise, the virtual env would default to whatever is your default python version, which may not be the version you want.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. That was an oversight in my answer. You also have to specify the version you want to install. Thank you.

Comment: @Gino Mempin Question was marked duplicate but  I've improved my answer. Glad you pointed that out.