# How to change Python version VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

***NOTE***: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135624/how-can-i-change-the-python-version-in-visual-studio-code), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77504333/how-do-i-update-my-python-version-in-vs-code), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76832567/how-do-i-change-python-versions-on-vs-code) do ***NOT*** answer my question.

I recently(ish) downloaded Python v3.12 onto my laptop (Windows OS). I want to get this version of Python onto VS Code too.
Current Python version:
[image: current Python version]

I clicked on the version of Python that VS is currently using, and typed in `Python: select interpreter`. I clicked on it, but the only versions of Python are what's below:
[image: Python interpreter versions]

Comment: If you know where you installed python 3.12, you can search for that with "Enter interpreter path...".

Comment: Windows OS and your paths are `/usr/local/python/`

Comment: try restarting VS Code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried entering the path? It needs to point to the `pythonw.exe` and not the `python.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Select `Enter interpreter path...` and paste your `python.exe` absolute path.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do I find the path? I tried to find it as directed by a comment, but I didn't know where it might be.

Comment: The path where you installed it. Or you can reinstall and choose a path you are familiar with.